# .net 4.0 with Code Access Security NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy won't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, code-access-security

I'm trying to use an external library DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v8.1.dll in my vsto office addin built using VS2010 beta 2.  I am getting the following ***compile time***  error:

DevExpress.Utils.AppareanceObject threw an exception --> System.NotSupportedException.

The error message goes on to say that for compatibility reasons I can use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy switch.

I've tried putting this config variable in all of the following locations:

1) my applications config file.
2) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\msbuild.exe.config
3) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\dev.exe.config

None of these have resolved the problem. Here were the references I've used.

[re-enable cas](http://blogs.rev-net.com/ddewinter/2009/05/20/opting-out-of-security-changes-in-net-4/comment-page-1/#comment-9088)

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191568(VS.100).aspx

How do I get rid of this error so I can build the application in vs 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LC.exe fails to process license information of devexpress 9.1.4 dlls
Update: Looks like this program is related to lc.exe. create a file called lc.exe.config that contains

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\ (NETFX 4.0 Tools) solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

This does work, however, you'll also need to create a file for devenv.exe.config to edit form designer changes, and the side effect of that is that COM references in project's will give obscure errors.

The end result, is that we really need an update from DevExpress on this.  Allegedly a beta fix with a 2010.1 release is due any time now, come on DevExpress, hurry up! :)